# Deleting Elements in an Array if Element is a Certain value VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, element

I have a global array, `prLst()` that be can of variable length.  It takes in numbers as strings `"1"` to `Ubound(prLst)`.  However, when the user enters `"0"`, I want to delete that element from the list.  I have the following code written to perform this:

```
count2 = 0
eachHdr = 1
totHead = UBound(prLst)

Do
    If prLst(eachHdr) = "0" Then
        prLst(eachHdr).Delete
        count2 = count2 + 1
    End If
    keepTrack = totHead - count2
    'MsgBox "prLst = " & prLst(eachHdr)
    eachHdr = eachHdr + 1
Loop Until eachHdr > keepTrack
```

This does not work. How do I efficiently delete elements in the array `prLst` if the element is `"0"`?

---

**NOTE:** This is part of a larger program, for which the description of can be found here: [Sorting Groups of Rows Excel VBA Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671273/excel-vba-macro-sorting-with-groups-or-linked-rows)

Comment: It might not help in your use case, but if this was a worksheet function, you could use `FILTER()` to remove the zeros from an array.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

An array is a structure with a certain size. You can use dynamic arrays in vba that you can shrink or grow using ReDim but you can't remove elements in the middle. It's not clear from your sample how your array functionally works or how you determine the index position (eachHdr) but you basically have 3 options

(A) Write a custom 'delete' function for your array like (untested)

```
Public Sub DeleteElementAt(Byval index As Integer, Byref prLst as Variant)
       Dim i As Integer
        
        ' Move all element back one position
        For i = index + 1 To UBound(prLst)
            prLst(i - 1) = prLst(i)
        Next
        
        ' Shrink the array by one, removing the last one
        ReDim Preserve prLst(LBound(prLst) To UBound(prLst) - 1)
End Sub
```

(B) Simply set a 'dummy' value as the value instead of actually deleting the element

```
If prLst(eachHdr) = "0" Then        
   prLst(eachHdr) = "n/a"
End If
```

(C) Stop using an array and change it into a VBA.Collection. A collection is a (unique)key/value pair structure where you can freely add or delete elements from

```
Dim prLst As New Collection
```

Comment: For collections, do the lengths of the collections ever have to be specified or "ReDimmed"? Also, can you loop through through collections element by element , arranging elements in a specific order? In addition, do you have to loop through to delete, or is there a way to say "all elements that are 'this', delete!" ?

Comment: No, the length of a collection does not have to be "redimmed" by you, the user. This makes collections much more convenient than arrays for tasks where items need to be added and removed. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/yb7y698k%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Lot of questions:) No redim needed. Yes you can loop through them and you insert element before or after other elements. Elements can be accessed by their index number (like the index in the array) or by the name of the key. Look further at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164019(v=office.10).aspx#odc_tentipsvba_topic4 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y8b3b3(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: After reading that this is still rather confusing.  Originally, for my program I had been using arrays.  Now I am using collection objects and simply want to delete all items in prLst with a "0", but I want to be able to know the index of which item i am deleting.  So i can eventually delete an element of another collection headRow at the according index.

Comment: Create a new question for that about how to use a collection for what you want. We can't answer your questions without more information over what you are trying to store where and how and how those things relate. You probably shouldn't store "0" values and use multiple collections (or array) but create a custom object with all those things as properties and store/use those.

Comment: this is not "Move all elements back one position", it is actually "Move all elements ahead one position"in the comment

Comment: How is this a highly rated and accepted answer when `Len(Array())` is a Type-Mismatch error? This code isn't usable as is. The shrink line should read `ReDim Preserve thisArray(LBound(prLst) To UBound(prLst) -1)`

Comment: I'm trying to modify this code to work on an array from a range. So the array is 2D but the only values are in the (i, 1) positions. I am getting a Subscript out of range error on my Redim line....

```Public Sub DeleteElementAt(ByVal index As Integer, ByRef Arr As Variant)
       Dim i As Integer

        ' Move all element back one position
        For i = index + 1 To UBound(Arr)
            Arr(index, 1) = Arr(i, 1)
        Next i

        ' Shrink the array by one, removing the last one
        ReDim Preserve Arr(LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr) - 1, 1)
End Sub```

ideas?

Answer (score 2):

here is a sample of code using the `CopyMemory` function to do the job.

It is supposedly "much faster" (depending of the size and type of the array...).

i am not the author, but i tested it :

```
Sub RemoveArrayElement_Str(ByRef AryVar() As String, ByVal RemoveWhich As Long) 

'// The size of the array elements
'// In the case of string arrays, they are
'// simply 32 bit pointers to BSTR's.
Dim byteLen As Byte

'// String pointers are 4 bytes
byteLen = 4

'// The copymemory operation is not necessary unless
'// we are working with an array element that is not
'// at the end of the array
If RemoveWhich < UBound(AryVar) Then
    '// Copy the block of string pointers starting at
    ' the position after the
    '// removed item back one spot.
    CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(AryVar(RemoveWhich)), ByVal _
        VarPtr(AryVar(RemoveWhich + 1)), (byteLen) * _
        (UBound(AryVar) - RemoveWhich)
End If

'// If we are removing the last array element
'// just deinitialize the array
'// otherwise chop the array down by one.
If UBound(AryVar) = LBound(AryVar) Then
    Erase AryVar
Else
    ReDim Preserve AryVar(LBound(AryVar) To UBound(AryVar) - 1)
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub DelEle(Ary, SameTypeTemp, Index As Integer) '<<<<<<<<< pass only not fixed sized array (i don't know how to declare same type temp array in proceder)
    Dim I As Integer, II As Integer
    II = -1
    If Index < LBound(Ary) And Index > UBound(Ary) Then MsgBox "Error.........."
    For I = 0 To UBound(Ary)
        If I <> Index Then
            II = II + 1
            ReDim Preserve SameTypeTemp(II)
            SameTypeTemp(II) = Ary(I)
        End If
    Next I
    ReDim Ary(UBound(SameTypeTemp))
    Ary = SameTypeTemp
    Erase SameTypeTemp
End Sub

Sub Test()
    Dim a() As Integer, b() As Integer
    ReDim a(3)
    Debug.Print "InputData:"
    For I = 0 To UBound(a)
        a(I) = I
        Debug.Print "    " & a(I)
    Next
    DelEle a, b, 1
    Debug.Print "Result:"
    For I = 0 To UBound(a)
        Debug.Print "    " & a(I)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Code-only answers are rarely good. It's best to add some text explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the array, why not just skip over the 0s and save yourself the time of having to worry about them later? As mentioned above, arrays are not well-suited for deletion.

Comment: This code is part of a larger code that I am creating found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671273/excel-vba-macro-sorting-with-groups-or-linked-rows  This code is part of the sub EstSortPriorities.  Because the program does not know which headers are the ones to sort at the top of the sheet, the user must specify.  I have chosen that the user should enter a "0" if a sort priority was not wanted given a particular header.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to vba & excel - only been doing this for about 3 months -
I thought I'd share my array de-duplication method here as this post seems relevant to it:

This code if part of a bigger application that analyses pipe data-
Pipes are listed in a sheet with number in xxxx.1, xxxx.2, yyyy.1, yyyy.2 .... format. so thats why all the string manipulation exists.
basically it only collects the pipe number once only, and not the .2 or .1 part.

```
        With wbPreviousSummary.Sheets(1)
'   here, we will write the edited pipe numbers to a collection - then pass the collection to an array
        Dim PipeDict As New Dictionary

        Dim TempArray As Variant

        TempArray = .Range(.Cells(3, 2), .Cells(3, 2).End(xlDown)).Value

        For ele = LBound(TempArray, 1) To UBound(TempArray, 1)

            If Not PipeDict.Exists(Left(TempArray(ele, 1), Len(TempArray(ele, 1) - 2))) Then

                PipeDict.Add Key:=Left(TempArray(ele, 1), Len(TempArray(ele, 1) - 2)), _
                                                        Item:=Left(TempArray(ele, 1), Len(TempArray(ele, 1) - 2))

            End If

        Next ele

        TempArray = PipeDict.Items

        For ele = LBound(TempArray) To UBound(TempArray)
            MsgBox TempArray(ele)
        Next ele

    End With
    wbPreviousSummary.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Set wbPreviousSummary = Nothing 'done early so we dont have the information loaded in memory
```

Using a heap of message boxes for debugging atm - im sure you'll change it to suit your own work.

I hope people find this useful,
Regards
Joe

Comment: please dont run that exact code - lots of missing variables and some of the string work was wrong at the time i posted it.

Answer (score 0):

> Deleting Elements in an Array if Element is a Certain value VBA

to delete elements in an Array wih certain condition, you can code like this

```
For i = LBound(ArrValue, 2) To UBound(ArrValue, 2)
    If [Certain condition] Then
        ArrValue(1, i) = "-----------------------"
    End If
Next i

StrTransfer = Replace(Replace(Replace(join(Application.Index(ArrValue(), 1, 0), ","), ",-----------------------,", ",", , , vbBinaryCompare), "-----------------------,", "", , , vbBinaryCompare), ",-----------------------", "", , , vbBinaryCompare)
ResultArray = join( Strtransfer, ",")
```

I often manipulate 1D-Array with Join/Split
but if you have to delete certain value in Multi Dimension I suggest you to change those Array into 1D-Array like this

```
strTransfer = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Names.Add("A", MultiDimensionArray), Chr(34), ""), "={", ""), "}", ""), ";", ",")
'somecode to edit Array like 1st code on top of this comment
'then loop through this strTransfer to get right value in right dimension
'with split function.
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but here's the solution I came up with when I didn't like the ones I found.

-Loop through the array (Variant) adding each element and some divider to a string, unless it matches the one you want to remove
-Then split the string on the divider

```
tmpString=""
For Each arrElem in GlobalArray
   If CStr(arrElem) = "removeThis" Then
      GoTo SkipElem
   Else
      tmpString =tmpString & ":-:" & CStr(arrElem)
   End If
SkipElem:
Next
GlobalArray = Split(tmpString, ":-:")
```

Obviously the use of strings creates some limitations, like needing to be sure of the information already in the array, and as-is this code makes the first array element blank, but it does what I need and with a little more work it could be more versatile.

Comment: nice and simple approach. needs a tad of tweaking though since the first value of the array will always automatically be blank

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. I did it the following way to get a string with unique values (from two columns of an output sheet):

```
Dim startpoint, endpoint, ArrCount As Integer
Dim SentToArr() As String

'created by running the first part (check for new entries)
startpoint = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("temp").Range("A1").Value
'set counter on 0
Arrcount = 0 
'last filled row in BG
endpoint = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BG").Range("G1047854").End(xlUp).Row

'create arr with all data - this could be any data you want!
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BG")
    For i = startpoint To endpoint
        ArrCount = ArrCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve SentToArr(1 To ArrCount)
        SentToArr(ArrCount) = .Range("A" & i).Value
        'get prep
        ArrCount = ArrCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve SentToArr(1 To ArrCount)
        SentToArr(ArrCount) = .Range("B" & i).Value
    Next i
End With

'iterate the arr and get a key (l) in each iteration
For l = LBound(SentToArr) To UBound(SentToArr)
    Key = SentToArr(l)
    'iterate one more time and compare the first key (l) with key (k)
    For k = LBound(SentToArr) To UBound(SentToArr)
        'if key = the new key from the second iteration and the position is different fill it as empty
        If Key = SentToArr(k) And Not k = l Then
            SentToArr(k) = ""
        End If
    Next k
Next l

'iterate through all 'unique-made' values, if the value of the pos is 
'empty, skip - you could also create a new array by using the following after the IF below - !! dont forget to reset [ArrCount] as well:
'ArrCount = ArrCount + 1
'ReDim Preserve SentToArr(1 To ArrCount)
'SentToArr(ArrCount) = SentToArr(h)

For h = LBound(SentToArr) To UBound(SentToArr)
    If SentToArr(h) = "" Then GoTo skipArrayPart
    GetEmailArray = GetEmailArray & "; " & SentToArr(h)
skipArrayPart:
Next h

'some clean up
If Left(GetEmailArray, 2) = "; " Then
    GetEmailArray = Right(GetEmailArray, Len(GetEmailArray) - 2)
End If

'show us the money
MsgBox GetEmailArray
```