# Remove item during for loop

Tags: vba, collections, for-loop, excel-2007

What does `tlist` contain after I do:

```
Dim tlist As Collection
tlist.Add ("AA")
tlist.Add ("BB")
tlist.Add ("CC")
tlist.Add ("DD")

For i = 1 To tlist.Count
    If i = 2 Then tList.Remove (2)
Next
```

I am hoping it will be:

```
Index | Value
-------------
1     |  "AA"
3     |  "BB"
4     |  "CC"
```

But I fear it will be:

```
Index | Value
-------------
1     |  "AA"
```

---

---

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
Dim tlist As Collection
tlist.Add ("KA")
tlist.Add ("KIC")
tlist.Add ("KS")
tlist.Add ("NC")

' Loop through each cell in row.
For Each mycells In myrow.Columns
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Loop through each regex in list.
    For i = 1 To tlist.Count
        matches = Regex(tlist(i))

        ' If match found in cell, copy row, and remove element (to prevent duplicate rows).
        If matches >= 1 Then
            Call CopyRow(myrow, _
                         ActiveSheet.Index, _
                         ActiveSheet.Index + i)

            tlist.Remove (i)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Is `Collection` even the right data type to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question the item removed from the collection will be "BB". The other items will remain. You are simply removing the second item in the list: .Remove(2)

To answer your second question: IT depends on what you are doing.  I nearly always prefer to work with the dictionary object.  It has more functionality and you can check if an element exists and assign an item to each key.

```
'// Using With but you could use Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    .Add "AA", Nothing
    .Add "BB", Nothing
    .Add "CC", Nothing
    .Add "DD", Nothing

    If .exists("BB") Then .Remove ("BB")

    For Each Key In .keys
      Debug.Print Key
    Next Key

End With
```

Above code prints AA, CC, DD

Comment: @muntoo, do you still need more help?

Answer (score 1):

I aggree with Reafidy, a `Dictionary` would work better.

There a are also a number of other issues in your code.  Here's a refactored version.  Note that I have used early binding, so set a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` and `Microsoft VBScript Regular expressions 5.5`

```
Sub Muntoo()
    Dim re As RegExp
    Dim myCells As Range
    Dim myRow As Range
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim tlist As Dictionary

    On Error GoTo EH

    Set tlist = New Dictionary
    Set re = New RegExp

    tlist.Add 1, "KA"
    tlist.Add 2, "KIC"
    tlist.Add 3, "KS"
    tlist.Add 4, "NC"

    ' Set row reference 
    Set myRow = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveCell.EntireRow)  

    re.Global = True ' or false
    re.IgnoreCase = True ' or false

    ' Loop through each cell in row.
    For Each myCells In myRow.Cells
        ' Loop through each regex in list.
        If myCells.Value <> "" Then
            For Each Key In tlist.Keys
                re.Pattern = tlist.Item(Key)
                ' If match found in cell, copy row, and remove element (to prevent duplicate rows).
                If re.Test(myCells.Value) Then
                    Call CopyRow(myRow, _
                                 ActiveSheet.Index, _
                                 ActiveSheet.Index + Key)

                    tlist.Remove Key
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
CleanUp:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set re = Nothing
    tlist.RemoveAll
    Set tlist = Nothing
Exit Sub
EH:
    Resume
    GoTo CleanUp
End Sub

Private Sub CopyRow(rng As Range, i1 As Long, i2 As Long)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly, but if you want to remove an element at a specified index, you should look at the accepted answer of this question:

[Deleting Elements in an Array if Element is a Certain value VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000334/deleting-elements-in-an-array-if-element-is-a-certain-value-vba)

Seems to do what you want :)