# Excel VBA - Dynamic Userform with Add/Remove Object Functionality

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic-arrays, userform

I am trying to create a userform whereby people can place as many requests as they want with the ability to remove requests they no longer want, as well as other functionalities. I am having an issue with removing the dynamically created objects after the functions add-remove-add has been used in that sequence.

The code I have below has a snippet of the objects added to the userform along with dimension changes to the userform and objects already embedded in the userform. Other defined portions are not included below.

```
Dim RemoveButtonArray() As New Class_RemoveRequest

For i = Last To Last
    Set AddRemoveButton = GenPurchaseRequest.Controls.Add("Forms.Image.1", "btnRemove" & ObjID)
    With AddRemoveButton
        'properties
    End With
    Set AddRemoveLabel = GenPurchaseRequest.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lblRemove" & ObjID)
    With AddRemoveLabel
        'properties
    End With
    Set AddRequest = GenPurchaseRequest.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "Frame" & ObjID)
    With AddRequest
        'properties
        .Caption = "Purchase Request - " & ObjID
    End With
    With AddRequestButton
        .Top = 168 + (126 * i)
        .Left = 18
    End With
    With SubmitButton
        .Top = 168 + (126 * i)
        .Left = 200
    End With
    With CancelButton
        .Top = 168 + (126 * i)
        .Left = 381
    End With
    With GenPurchaseRequest
        .ScrollHeight = 200 + (126 * i)
        .ScrollTop = 200 + (126 * i)
    End With
ReDim Preserve RemoveButtonArray(0 To i)
Set RemoveButtonArray(i).RemoveButton = AddRemoveButton
Next i

ObjID = ObjID + 1
Last = Last + 1
```

This works well and the form is populated with everything correctly. When the user removes a request, the below code works fine as well:

```
Public WithEvents RemoveButton As MSForms.Image

Private Sub RemoveButton_click()

Dim ConfirmRemoval As Integer
Dim rbRefNo As String
Dim rbRefNoConvert As Integer

ConfirmRemoval = MsgBox("Are you sure you would like to remove this request?", vbYesNo)

If ConfirmRemoval = vbYes Then
rbRefNo = Mid(Me.RemoveButton.Name, 10)
rbRefNoConvert = CInt(rbRefNo)
    With GenPurchaseRequest
        If Last > 1 Then
        .Controls.Remove ("Frame" & rbRefNo)
        .Controls.Remove ("btnRemove" & rbRefNo)
        .Controls.Remove ("lblRemove" & rbRefNo)

            For i = rbRefNoConvert + 1 To Last - 1
            .Controls("Frame" & i).Top = .Controls("Frame" & i).Top - 126
            .Controls("btnRemove" & i).Top = .Controls("btnRemove" & i).Top - 126
            .Controls("lblRemove" & i).Top = .Controls("lblRemove" & i).Top - 126
            Next i

        .AddRequestButton.Top = .AddRequestButton.Top - 126
        .SubmitButton.Top = .SubmitButton.Top - 126
        .CancelButton.Top = .CancelButton.Top - 126
        .ScrollTop = .ScrollTop - 126
        .ScrollHeight = .ScrollHeight - 126

        Last = Last - 1

         Else
         MsgBox "There is only one active Purchase Request."
         End If
     End With
Else
'do nothing
End If

End Sub
```

The user can then go back add additional requests as well as remove more requests that they no longer want. The problem arises when they add more requests and then attempt to remove the last one added directly after the removal. For example: I added 4 requests and then removed the 2nd one. I then added another request, but wanted to remove the 4th request, however, the remove button no longer works.

I believe that the issue is that I need to redefine the array used to store the removal buttons once the remove button function is called, however I have no idea how to do that. My current attempt at doing that is:

```
For j = 0 To Last
If j = rbRefNoConvert Then
j = j + 1
Else
ReDim RemoveButtonArray(0 To j)
Set RemoveButtonArray(j).RemoveButton = AddRemoveButton
End If
Next j
```

But that object reference is incorrect and I do not know how to reference it correctly. I tried referencing the control itself, but that did not work.

I am very new to the use of class modules, arrays, and dynamic userforms, so sorry for the lengthy question!

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: There's a lot of code there, so it's difficult to figure out exactly what's going on.  A simpler example using just an array of buttons probably would be easier to follow.  Instead of re-organizing your array whenever an order is deleted, you can just set that member in the array to Nothing, then add any new orders to the end of the array (extending as required).  To re-arrange the form layout just loop over the array, ignoring the "empty" members.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7000798/1698517) that shows how to delete an element from an array may be helpful.

Comment: @TimWilliams - The only controls that I am using with arrays will be the the controls that need an event handler. Using your example, would I need to place all of my controls into individual arrays?

Comment: I think there's too much code here and too many missing pieces: that's going to make testing difficult for anyone else.  Unless you can share the workbook you might not get much help on this...

Comment: @TimWilliams - Is it best to post questions with a simplified code with the same issue rather than the real code?

Also, I was able to solve the issue. Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed your problem.  As for posting code - it's generally best to post something which can be tested by someone who is interested in helping, without them having to expend too much effort in recreating the issue. Either making the complete workbook available (particularly if it's quite a complex issue) *or* posting a simplified/minimal example which demonstrates the problem are probably the best approaches.

Comment: @TimWilliams - Thanks! I will keep that in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted a couple of things:

(1) Setting the reference to the control I wanted to delete as nothing in the array.

(2) Adding the controls to a collection rather than a dynamic array.

None of the above worked, so instead I used this last method.

(3) I cleared the text values of the controls that needed to be removed. Then, using a for loop, I moved all the text values of the controls after the ones I wanted to delete to the above frames. Then, I removed the last control, redefined the array (when the user clicks the button again to add another set of controls), and redefined my counter. The code is represented below.

```
Public WithEvents RemoveButton As MSForms.Image

Private Sub RemoveButton_click()

'Defines appropriate variables
Dim ConfirmRemoval As Integer
Dim rbRefNo As String
Dim rbRefNoConvert As Integer

'Asks user for input to remove a control
ConfirmRemoval = MsgBox("Are you sure you would like to remove this request?", vbYesNo)

If ConfirmRemoval = vbYes Then
'Extracts the name identifier from the control to be removed and also converts it into a number
rbRefNo = Mid(Me.RemoveButton.Name, 10)
rbRefNoConvert = CInt(rbRefNo)
With GenPurchaseRequest
    If ObjID > 1 Then
        'Loops through the dynamic form controls and adjusts the user-inputs to account for the removed control
        For i = rbRefNoConvert To ObjID - 1
            If i < (ObjID - 1) Then
                .Controls("txtVendor" & i).Text = .Controls("txtVendor" & i + 1).Text
                .Controls("txtItem" & i).Text = .Controls("txtItem" & i + 1).Text
                .Controls("txtQuantity" & i).Text = .Controls("txtQuantity" & i + 1).Text
                .Controls("txtProject" & i).Value = .Controls("txtProject" & i + 1).Value
                .Controls("txtCatalog" & i).Text = .Controls("txtCatalog" & i + 1).Text
                .Controls("txtDate" & i).Value = .Controls("txtDate" & i + 1).Value
            Else
                .Controls("txtVendor" & i).Text = .Controls("txtVendor" & i).Text
                .Controls("txtItem" & i).Text = .Controls("txtItem" & i).Text
                .Controls("txtQuantity" & i).Text = .Controls("txtQuantity" & i).Text
                .Controls("txtProject" & i).Value = .Controls("txtProject" & i).Value
                .Controls("txtCatalog" & i).Text = .Controls("txtCatalog" & i).Text
                .Controls("txtDate" & i).Value = .Controls("txtDate" & i).Value
            End If
        Next i
        'Removes selected remove button and associated form controls
        .Controls.Remove ("Frame" & ObjID - 1)
        .Controls.Remove ("AddRequestOptions" & ObjID - 1)
        'Re-formats userform to adjust for removed controls
        .AddRequestButton.Top = .AddRequestButton.Top - 126
        .CopyRequestButton.Top = .CopyRequestButton.Top - 126
        .SubmitButton.Top = .SubmitButton.Top - 126
        .CancelButton.Top = .CancelButton.Top - 126
        .ScrollTop = .ScrollTop - 126
        .ScrollHeight = .ScrollHeight - 126
        'Adjusts the object identifier variable to account for removed control
        ObjID = ObjID - 1
    Else
        MsgBox "There is only one active Purchase Request."
    End If
End With
Else
'do nothing
End If

End Sub
```