# Deleting directory in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have this code that gets all file types.

```
Dim file as variant
file = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files, *.*", , "Select File", , True)
```

Then I have to print it in the cells on a sheet.

```
For i = 1 To UBound(file)
    lRow = Cells(Rows.count, 15).End(xlUp).Row
    lRow = lRow + 1

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("O" & lRow).Value = CStr(file(i))
Next i
```

but what I want is first check the contents of the array. If the array has this file type, then I have to remove it in the arraylist. After that, a message will pop out that this files are removed.

```
dim arr() as string
arr = Split("ade|adp|app|asp|bas|bat|cer|chm|cmd|com|cpl|crt|csh|der|exe|fxp|gadget|hlp|hta|inf|ins|isp|its|js|jse|" _
& "ksh|lnk|mad|maf|mag|mam|maq|mar|mas|mat|mau|mav|maw|mda|mdb|mde|mdt|mdw|mdz|msc|msh|msh1|msh2|" _
& "mshxml|msh1xml|msh2xml|ade|adp|app|asp|bas|bat|cer|chm|cmd|com|cpl|crt|csh|der|exe|fxp|gadget|hlp|" _
& "hta|msi|msp|mst|ops|pcd|pif|plg|prf|prg|pst|reg|scf|scr|sct|shb|shs|ps1|ps1xml|ps2|ps2xml|psc1|psc2|tmp|url|vb|vbe|vbs|vsmacros|vsw|ws|wsc|wsf|wsh|xnk", "|")
```

I just don't know where I have to start. I have found a little bit same problem [here in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000334/deleting-elements-in-an-array-if-element-is-a-certain-value-vba), but I just can't understand it. Thanks!

Comment: As suggested in the link did you look at [collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/yb7y698k%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)?

Comment: @DragonSamu I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with it. I'm still studying with it as of the moment, but just can't absorb it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to check that the extension it's not present in the blacklist with `InStr`:

```
Const exts = _
  ".ade.adp.app.asp.bas.bat.cer.chm.cmd.com.cpl.crt.csh.der.exe.fxp.gadget" & _
  ".hlp.hta.inf.ins.isp.its.js.jse.ksh.lnk.mad.maf.mag.mam.maq.mar.mas.mat" & _
  ".mau.mav.maw.mda.mdb.mde.mdt.mdw.mdz.msc.msh.msh1.msh2.mshxml.msh1xml" & _
  ".msh2xml.ade.adp.app.asp.bas.bat.cer.chm.cmd.com.cpl.crt.csh.der.exe.fxp" & _
  ".gadget.hlp.hta.msi.msp.mst.ops.pcd.pif.plg.prf.prg.pst.reg.scf.scr.sct" & _
  ".shb.shs.ps1.ps1xml.ps2.ps2xml.psc1.psc2.tmp.url.vb.vbe.vbs.vsmacros.vsw" & _
  ".ws.wsc.wsf.wsh.xnk."

Dim file As Variant
file = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files, *.*", , "Select File", , True)

Dim i As Long, data(), count As Long, ext As String
ReDim data(1 To UBound(file) + 1, 1 To 1)

' filter the list
For i = LBound(file) To UBound(file)
  ext = LCase(Mid(file(i), InStrRev(file(i), ".")))
  If InStr(1, exts, ext & ".") = 0 Then  ' if not blacklisted
    count = count + 1
    data(count, 1) = file(i)
  End If
Next

' copy the filtered list to the next available row in column "O"
If count Then
  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Cells(Rows.count, "O").End(xlUp)
    .Offset(1).Resize(count).Value = data
  End With
End If
```

Comment: Is there any way to pop-out a message at the end what are the directories or files that are removed?

Comment: Yes, write each excluded file in a new array, then print the result with `MsgBox Join(excludedList, vbCrLf)`.

Comment: I've added this line `excludedFile(UBound(excludedFile)) = file(i)
    ReDim Preserve excludedFile(1 To UBound(excludedFile) + 1) As String` but says Subscript out of range. Am I doing this right? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `RegExp` and a varaint array to do this quickly

This code looks for *path... dot extension end string* so it is more robust than your current array which may remove files based on the path name rather than file type

```
Sub B()
Dim fName As Variant
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim rng1 As Range

Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

On Error Resume Next
fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files, *.*", , "Select file", , True)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo 0

With objRegex
 .Pattern = ".*\.(ade|adp|app|asp|bas|bat|cer|chm|cmd|com|cpl|crt|csh|der|exe|fxp|gadget|hlp|hta|inf|ins|isp|its|js|jse|" _
& "ksh|lnk|mad|maf|mag|mam|maq|mar|mas|mat|mau|mav|maw|mda|mdb|mde|mdt|mdw|mdz|msc|msh|msh1|msh2|" _
& "mshxml|msh1xml|msh2xml|ade|adp|app|asp|bas|bat|cer|chm|cmd|com|cpl|crt|csh|der|exe|fxp|gadget|hlp|" _
& "hta|msi|msp|mst|ops|pcd|pif|plg|prf|prg|pst|reg|scf|scr|sct|shb|shs|ps1|ps1xml|ps2|ps2xml|psc1|psc2|tmp|url|vb|vbe|vbs|vsmacros|vsw|ws|wsc|wsf|wsh|xnk)$"
    `replace matching file types with blank array entries
    For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(fName)
       fName(lngCnt) = .Replace(fName(lngCnt), vbNullString)
    Next
End With

Set rng1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
'dump array to sheet
rng1.Resize(UBound(fName), 1) = Application.Transpose(fName)
` remove blank entries
On Error Resume Next
rng1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlUp
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: If I have to delete the cell, there're still data below it and will also be deleted. Thanks

Comment: Any way to increment the range +1? Because the lastrow with data is overridden and replaced with a new one.