# Excel VBA - Type mismatch when redim arr

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I had an dynamic array where is value is from the worksheet.
If condition is meet, I would like to delete the element that meet the condition. The code was from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000334/deleting-elements-in-an-array-if-element-is-a-certain-value-vba) but it is returning

> Type Mismatch

on `ReDim Preserve arr(Len(arr) - 1)`

```
Sub arrtest()
Dim arr As Variant
Dim i As Integer

ReDim arr(1 To 1)

Dim cnt As Long
cnt = 0

For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row

    If Cells(i, "A").Value = "-2" Then
        cnt = cnt + 1
        ReDim Preserve arr(1 To cnt)
        arr(cnt) = Cells(i, "A").Value
    End If

Next i

    For i = 1 To cnt
        Debug.Print "This is arr: "; arr(i)

     If arr(i) = "TEST" Then
      Call DeleteElementAt(i, arr)
      Debug.Print "This is new arr: "; arr(i)
      Else
      Debug.Print "Nothing is deleted"
      End If
    Next

End Sub

Public Sub DeleteElementAt(ByVal index As Integer, ByRef arr As Variant)
       Dim i As Integer

        ' Move all element back one position
        For i = index + 1 To UBound(arr)
            arr(i - 1) = arr(i)
        Next
        ' Shrink the array by one, removing the last one
        ReDim Preserve arr(Len(arr) - 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Len (or Length) of an array is its Upper Boundary. To decrease the size of the array by 1,

```
ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) - 1)
```

Conversely, the beginning of an array is the LBound or lower boundary. This is usually 0 (zero) or 1 (one) and in a two-dimensioned array you can specify the rank.

Comment: Exactly. With `dim arr(0 to 4)` the ubound is 4. To *'Shrink the array by one, removing the last one'* you redim to 1 less than the ubound while preserving the existing values.

Comment: Alright, if I understood correctly, the `len()` returns `Long` and that causes the error.  Thanks for the explanation

Comment: The size of an array is the UBound; the number of cells in a range is the Count; the number of elements in a html collection is the length. They cannot seem to agree on anything.

Comment: @Jeeped There **is** a reason why `UBound` and `Count` aren't the same - imagine an arr declared as `Dim arr(8 To 20)` - if a `Count` property existed you would expect it to return 13, but you still need to know that the `UBound` is 20 and that the `LBound` is 8.