# How to delete item in VB array?

Tags: excel, vba

Here I want to delete source keys '566' in `TargetkyeArr()` after 
    `sourcekeys` is found in the array list.

```
TargetKeys = "566, 777, 888, 999, 1000"
Dim Arr() As String
TargetkeyArr() = Split(Targetkeys, ",")

Sourcekeys = 566
m = 0
Do While m <= (UBound(TargetKeyArr) - LBound(TargetkeyArr))
  If sourcekeys = Arr(m) Then
         MsgBox "Record found"
         Exit Do
   End If
m = m + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Copy the elements to a new array, excluding the found element

Comment: `Scripting.Dictionary` supports items removing.

Answer (score 0):

This should Work:

```
Targetkeys = "566, 777, 888, 999, 1000"

Dim Arr() As String
Dim m As Integer

Arr() = Split(Targetkeys, ",")

sourcekeys = 566

For m = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)

    If sourcekeys = Arr(m) Then

         MsgBox "Record found"

    End If

Next
```

Comment: Thank you. your code is correct and it works, I want to remove sourcekeys "566" in Arr() list since the record is found.   I want to know how to delete item in Array? could you please help

Comment: I don't think it's possible to remove elements from an array. You can use `ReDim Preserve` but that wouldn't help if you want to remove an element that is in the middle of your array. What you can do is to change it's value to `0` or something else that can be filtered out easily.

Comment: Look at this answer if you want to proceed with `ReDim Preserve` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000334/deleting-elements-in-an-array-if-element-is-a-certain-value-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the elements and exclude the value as the following:

```
Function ExcludeAValue(Arr As Variant, Var As Variant) As Variant
    Dim Arr2() As Variant, i As Long
    ReDim Arr2(0 To 0)
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        If Arr(i) <> Var Then
            If Not IsEmpty(Arr2(UBound(Arr2))) Then ReDim Preserve Arr2(0 To UBound(Arr2) + 1)
            Arr2(UBound(Arr2)) = Arr(i)
        End If
    Next
    ExcludeAValue = Arr2
End Function
```

Make sure to use the same data type when passing the vaules.

**Examples:**

```
Sub TestUsingString()
    Dim Targetkeys As String, Excludekey As String, TargetkeyArr As Variant
    Targetkeys = "566, 777, 888, 999, 1000"
    Excludekey = "566"
    TargetkeyArr = ExcludeAValue(Split(Targetkeys, ","), Excludekey)
End Sub
```

```
Sub TestUsingLong()
    Dim Targetkeys(0 To 4) As Long, Excludekey As Long, TargetkeyArr As Variant
    Targetkeys(0) = 566
    Targetkeys(1) = 777
    Targetkeys(2) = 888
    Targetkeys(3) = 999
    Targetkeys(4) = 1000
    Excludekey = 566
    TargetkeyArr = ExcludeAValue(Targetkeys, Excludekey)
End Sub
```

```
Sub BADTest()
    Dim Targetkeys As String, Excludekey As Long, TargetkeyArr As Variant
    'This one will not exclude it because 566 (long) <> "566" (string)
    Targetkeys = "566, 777, 888, 999, 1000"
    Excludekey = 566
    TargetkeyArr = ExcludeAValue(Split(Targetkeys, ","), Excludekey)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub RemoveItem()
    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection
    Targetkeys = "566, 777, 888, 999, 1000"
    Dim Arr() As String
    sourcekeys = "566"
    For Each Item In Split(Targetkeys, ",")
        ' if item is different, then add it to collection
        If Item <> sourcekeys Then c.Add (Item)
    Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all instances of the `sourceKey` value then you could use `Filter`

```
Dim TargetKeyArr As Variant
Dim sourceKeys As Long

TargetKeyArr = Array(566, 777, 888, 999, 1000)

sourceKeys = 566
TargetKeyArr = Filter(TargetKeyArr, sourceKeys, False)

MsgBox Join(TargetKeyArr, ", ")
```

Comment: Note: `Filter` will match (eg) "77" to "777" since it uses "contains" not "equals": ie it filters on substrings also.