# Sort groups of rows

Tags: excel, vba

I actually [found a page that I think has the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671273/sorting-groups-of-rows-excel-vba-macro) but I'm failing to understand it or how I can apply it to my application. I think the linked version sorts in groups by inserting new rows and cutting/pasting the rows. Unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation to comment yet, so I can't ask on the original question.

I want to do the same thing going from this:
[image]

To this:

[image]

My questions is is the linked question what I'm actually looking for? I'm failing to see how the loops in the supplied code actually sort the rows.

Comment: Assuming a relatively small number of lines, copy the "Headers" to fill the blank cells, then re-sort at will from the [Data] tab - no need for a single line of code. If you need to then remove the "Headers", either pivot the resulting table, or write a macro with a loop that starts at the top and deletes the "headers" whenever it's the same as that of the previous row.

Comment: Those cells are only sometimes blank. And there are currently 233 rows. This number will not always be the same.

Comment: In any case your question is *too broad* to be answerabe here; you need to *try something* and show us what you've got and describe what's not working / what error you're getting. Don't just grab code from the Internet, break down the steps required to achieve what you need to do, then break these down into sub-steps; figure out what the inputs are and what the output is for each, then write a procedure/function for each of these sub-steps. You can't ask "how do I do this" and walk away with a answer you can just copy-paste. If you have a *specific* question about the loops, ask it!

Comment: Understandable. I'll go back and redo what I currently have and see what I can do to make my question more specific once I have access to my computer tomorrow. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The linked question uses what I believe is called a bubble sort.  This is a slow sort with the best implementation and this is a poor implementation.  I would identify the first unused column; call it N.  I would copy the headers from column 1 to column N filling in the gaps.  I would use Excel’s sort on column N.  Finally, I would delete column N.  Adjusting a sort for the current number of rows is a bit of a pain but otherwise this is all simple, fast VBA.

Comment: Note that an Excel sort will sort all the 2 rows together but will not preserve the sequence of the 2 rows.  Look up “stable sorting” for a better explanation of this point.  There is fix for this if necessary.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon 's suggestion can be implemented with a helper column and the following formula: `=IF(ISBLANK(A2),C1,A2)`. you can then sort on the helper column and remove it

Answer (score 0):

## Sort Vertically Titled Groups feat. Range, Array, BubbleSort

[image]

Adjust the **4** values in the **constants** section carefully not to lose data.
The 'Test Checker' `blnTest` is set to `True` i.e. the code is in **Test Mode** and will paste the sorted data to the range starting with the `cStrFirstTest` cell range. If you change `blnTest` to `False`, the initial data will be **replaced** i.e. the sorted data will be pasted into the range starting with the `cStrFirstCell` cell range, as requested.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SortVerticalGroups()

  Const cStrFirstCell As String = "A2"  ' First Cell Range of Data
  Const intLastColumn As Integer = 3    ' Last Column of Data
  Const cStrFirstTest As String = "D2"  ' Test First Cell Range of Data
  Const blnTest As Boolean = True       ' Test Checker

  Dim vntData As Variant    ' Data Array
  Dim vntGroup As Variant   ' Group Array
  Dim vntSort As Variant    ' Sort Array

  Dim lngR1 As Long         ' Data Array Rows & Sort Outer Counter
  Dim lngR2 As Long         ' Group Count, Group Array Rows & Sort Inner Counter
  Dim lngR3 As Long         ' Sort Array Rows Counter
  Dim iCol As Integer       ' Data Array & Sort Array Columns Counter
  Dim iTemp As Integer      ' Sort Temporary Data Storage
  Dim strRange As String    ' Sort Range's First Cell

  ' Paste range into array.
  With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    vntData = .Range( _
        cStrFirstCell, _
        Cells( _
          .Range(.Range(cStrFirstCell), Cells(Rows.Count, intLastColumn)) _
            .Find(What:="*", _
            After:=.Range(cStrFirstCell), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row, _
          intLastColumn))
  End With

  ' Count the number of Groups.
  For lngR1 = 1 To UBound(vntData)
    If vntData(lngR1, 1) <> "" Then
      lngR2 = lngR2 + 1
    End If
  Next

  ' Write groups to Group Array.
  ReDim vntGroup(1 To lngR2, 1 To 1)
  lngR2 = 0
  For lngR1 = 1 To UBound(vntData)
    If vntData(lngR1, 1) <> "" Then
      lngR2 = lngR2 + 1
      vntGroup(lngR2, 1) = vntData(lngR1, 1)
    End If
  Next

  ' Sort Group Array.
  For lngR1 = 1 To UBound(vntGroup) - 1
    For lngR2 = lngR1 + 1 To UBound(vntGroup)
      If vntGroup(lngR1, 1) > vntGroup(lngR2, 1) Then
        iTemp = vntGroup(lngR1, 1)
        vntGroup(lngR1, 1) = vntGroup(lngR2, 1)
        vntGroup(lngR2, 1) = iTemp
      End If
    Next
  Next

  ' Write sorted data to Sort Array.
  ReDim vntSort(1 To UBound(vntData), 1 To UBound(vntData, 2))
  For lngR2 = 1 To UBound(vntGroup)
    For lngR1 = 1 To UBound(vntData)
      If vntData(lngR1, 1) = vntGroup(lngR2, 1) Then
        Do
          lngR3 = lngR3 + 1
          For iCol = 1 To UBound(vntData, 2)
            vntSort(lngR3, iCol) = vntData(lngR1, iCol)
          Next
          lngR1 = lngR1 + 1
          If lngR1 > UBound(vntData) Then Exit Do
        Loop Until vntData(lngR1, 1) <> ""
      End If
    Next
  Next

  ' Check if test or for real.
  If blnTest Then
    strRange = cStrFirstTest
   Else
    strRange = cStrFirstCell
  End If

  ' Paste Sort Array into range.
  With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
      .Range(strRange).Resize(UBound(vntSort), UBound(vntSort, 2)) = vntSort
  End With

End Sub
```